# Ionic 2 : Undefined is not an object

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.email = '123'')

Why is this happening?

My Ionic 2 code in controller:

```
email:string = '' ;

facebook_login() {

    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'email'])
        .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {

            this.fb.api("/me?fields=name,email", []).then(function(user) {

                this.email = '123' ;

            }) ;

    }).catch(e => {
        alert('Error login') ;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function as callback `() => {}`.

The `this` will point to the function object rather than the class in your example.

```
this.fb.api("/me?fields=name,email", []).then(function(user) {

                this.email = '123' ;

            }) ;
```

Change the above to:

```
this.fb.api("/me?fields=name,email", []).then((user) => {

                this.email = '123' ;

            }) ;
```

Comment: Can you please guide me, how can i run a native ios SDK in my ionic project. Your help is highly needed.